# Sharepoint stops debugging

Tags: c#, debugging, sharepoint-2010, visual-studio-2013, web-parts

I've been working on a few webparts to create and interact with subsites. When I started out I didn't run into any troubles, but over time the debugger just seems to crap out.
When I hit F5 it starts retracting, building and deploying. When it reaches the point of loading the page the browser window just closes and the status bar simply says 'ready'. Every now and then it allows me to run through my code.

I've tried a few things like cleaning, rebuilding and retracting before debugging. Rebooting Visual Studio and the system as a whole.

My system isn't the fastest and just waiting a few minutes to get nothing out of it is getting really frustrating. It's gotten to a point where I've just started inserting labels and step counters to get some helpful information through deployment.